# adjust the space between text and button border using flex in css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I try to create a Button with icon and text inside of it and set up CSS using flex. How can I write CSS so I can set up space between the Text inside of the button and border of button? In my attached image, I want to change space on left from 16px to 4px without changing the margin from icon. I try to use padding. but it does not work

```css
.btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 8px 16px 8px;
  width: 163px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.fa-folder {
  margin-left: 8px;
}


/* Darker background on mouse-over */

.btn:hover {
  background-color: RoyalBlue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button class="btn">Text Text<i class="fa fa-folder"></i></button>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have added span in button added padding-left to right.

```css
.btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 8px 16px 8px;
  width: 163px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.btn span{
  padding: 0px 16px 0px 8px;
}
.fa-folder {
  margin-left: 8px;
}

/* Darker background on mouse-over */
.btn:hover {
  background-color: RoyalBlue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Add icon library -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button class="btn"><span>Text Text</span><i class="fa fa-folder"></i></button>
</body>

</html>
```